# Material Ui Tab show data from Api call

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I am fetching data from backend to show some meal information. There are are filters to filter out each category . Currently I am showing the filter out data by clicking a button . Each time I click a button corresponding filtered data is shown . Now what I want to do is instead of using buttons I want to use Material Ui Tabs component . I am relatively new to Materia Ui . I am not understanding how can I can show the filtered data using the Material Ui Tab component . My code is given below -

Home.jsx

```
const value = useContext(DataContext);
  const [foods, setFood] = value.foods;

  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(["all"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = foods.map((food) => ({
      ...food,
      filtered: food.category.includes(tabs),
    }));
    setFood(filtered);
  }, [tabs]);

  const handleFilter = (tabs) => {
    setTabs(tabs);
    console.log(tabs);
    // console.log(foods);
  };

  return (
    
     
        <TabsData handleFilter={handleFilter}></TabsData>
```

TabsData.jsx

```
const TabsData = ({ handleFilter }) => {
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("all")}>
        All
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Salad/Soup")}>
        Salad/Soup
      </button>
      <button
        className="btn"
        onClick={() => handleFilter("Starter/Side Order")}
      >
        Starter/Side Order
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Breakfast Item")}>
        Breakfast Item
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Asian Classic")}>
        Asian Classic
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Chicken")}>
        Chicken
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Pasta")}>
        Pasta
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Western")}>
        Western
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Pizza")}>
        Pizza
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleFilter("Desert")}>
        Desert
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Materia-UI with very little effort.
By the way, there are a lot of examples in the documentation that can help you: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#tabs

Back to your question:
You just have to iterate over your fetched categories and create a tab and a TabPanel (The TabPanel is just a custom component to render the content which should be displayed for a specific tab).

Your currentTab state determines which tab is currently active and should be displayed.

Here is an example:

```js
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

function TabPanel({ children, value, index, ...other }) {
  return (
    <div role="tabpanel" hidden={value !== index} {...other}>
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newTab) => {
    setCurrentTab(newTab);
  };
  const fetchedCategories = [
    {
      label: "All",
      description: "All description"
    },
    {
      label: "Salad/Soup",
      description: "Salad/Soup description"
    },
    {
      label: "Starter/Side Order",
      description: "Starter/Side Order description"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={currentTab}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="simple tabs example"
        >
          {fetchedCategories.map((category) => (
            <Tab key={category.label} label={category.label} />
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {fetchedCategories.map((category, index) => (
        <TabPanel key={category.label} value={currentTab} index={index}>
          {category.description}
        </TabPanel>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Live Demo

[image: Edit material-ui-tab-show-data-from-api-call]